# cannot open local json file {open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)}

Tags: android, json, gson

I'm trying to access a json file from /res folder:

```
convertJsonToObject(String fileName) {

Car car = new Car();
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new FileReader(fileName));
Gson builder = new GsonBuilder();
Gson gson = builder.create();
car = gson.fromJson(reader, Car.class);
return car;
}
```

I have used jUnit to test the method and it's working properly. But when I deploy the library as apk and use it in my app. I get that json file cannot be opened.

What could be the problem causing this ? I have all the permissions.

Comment: i think you havnt get runtime permissions from user is your OS is 6.0?

Comment: version is 5.0.1 and the format of the fileName i'm sending is res/example.json